# Use of generators under metadata in ARM Templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

What is the use of the highlighted part in the Azure ARM Templates' JSON structure? Where does the resource use it?

[image: ARM Templates JSON]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resource manager ignores the metadata at the time of deployment. This is just for you to share the more information about the template and its resources with other developers.

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/syntax#metadata):

> You can add a metadata object almost anywhere in your template.
> Resource Manager ignores the object, but your JSON editor may warn you
> that the property isn't valid. In the object, define the properties
> you need.

A caveat here is when you define `metadata` with `description` property for your template parameters. When you deploy the template through Azure Portal, the description is shown as a tool tip for that parameter.

[image]

Comment: But I was more concerned about the key by the value "bicep". Juz wondering what that might mean

Comment: Oh..I think that means is that this template was written using [`bicep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/overview) instead of directly writing template using JSON.